# Laravel query with relationships and conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Hi I have 3 tables in DB. Here is my query:

```
$nav = PageNav::with([
                    'page' => function($query) {
                        $query->where('status', 1)
                              ->where(function($query) {
                                    $query->whereNull('publish_up')
                                          ->whereNull('publish_down');
                                })
                              ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                                    $query->where('publish_up', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                                          ->where('publish_down', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                                });
                    },
                    'langs' => function ($query) use ($lang) {$query->where('language_code', '=', $lang);},
                ])
                ->get();
```

It generates this queries:
[image]

When I loop $nav there are still pages with status = 0. I really don't understand why? Any suggestions?

Comment: Rather than inserting an image of your generated queries, which is both hard to read b/c it is scaled down, and impossible to select & copy, or search, would you please copy and paste that in as a code block?

Comment: Perhaps you could try using scopes to simplify your issue here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes

Answer (score 4):

As with any SQL query or Eloquent query, `OR` completely separates the conditions, so as soon as you have an `orWhere` in eloquent, it will match anything that matches before the OR or after the OR.

You can resolve this by using a nested where, or parentheses in SQL, to properly encapsulate the conditions.

```
    $query->where('status', 1)
          ->whereNested(function($q1) {
               $q1->where(function($query) {
                    $query->whereNull('publish_up')
                          ->whereNull('publish_down');
                })
               ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                    $query->where('publish_up', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                          ->where('publish_down', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                });
           });
```

Comment: Ok I understand... but still get also page where status=0. I think problem is that I'm accessing PageNav model with relationship to Page and PageLang model. Status is stored in Page table not in PageNav.
I can't access it through Page model because I'm using Baum extension for Laravel and it's table is in PageNav

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found solution. Needed to wrap condition to whereHas

```
$nav = PageNav::whereHas('page', function ($query) {
                        $query->where('status', 1)
                              ->whereNested(function($q1) {
                                  $q1->where(function($query) {
                                        $query->whereNull('publish_up')
                                              ->whereNull('publish_down');
                                    })
                                  ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                                        $query->where('publish_up', '<', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                                              ->where('publish_down', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                                    });
                              });
                    })
                    ->with([
                    'page',
                    'langs' => function ($query) use ($lang) {
                        $query->where('language_code', '=', $lang);
                    }
                ])
                ->get();
```